# How to programmatically update content in a SharePoint 2010 content editor Web Part using the CSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, csom

So I have no clue where to even start with this. I have tried Google to no avail.

My boss had me add a scrolling marquee to one of our SharePoint sites, using a content editor web part. He now wants me to be able to update it once a day from an excel document on a shared drive. I can open and read the excel file with no issue. The thing is that I only have access to what can be done via the CSOM, and so far I can't find a way to update this web part that way.

Anything would be great!

Answer (score 0):

1. Get XmlString for content editor webpart using webservice "_vti_bin/WebPartPages.asmx". If you want to see all methods of this web service then navigate to "Sharepointsiteurl/_vti_bin/WebPartPages.asmx".
2. There is a method GetwebPart2 . Using this method retrieve xmlstring. This XmlString contains all information including content of content editor webpart.

3.You have to replace your old content with your new content.
4.Save webpart using savewebpart method with your new xmlString